# Is a 2D fallback needed for translate3d in situations where the client's machine has no 3D support?

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms, translate3d

Is it required to have a 2D fallback (`translateX`, e.g.) for `translate3d` in a possible (but rare?) situation where the browser can't allocate 3D resources (in case of a really old graphics card, for example).

Comment: [caniuse: CSS3 3D Transforms](http://caniuse.com/#search=translate3d)

Comment: That wasn't my question. To be clear: my question was, if the browser cannot somehow allocate 3D resources (really terrible graphics card, for example), does it automatically fall back to regular `translate`, or do I have to provide a CSS fallback myself?

Comment: Maybe it's a non-issue? Most computers these days can do some rudimentary 3D, especially if it's just a browser moving some text or an SVG.

Comment: I edited my question to make it more focused.